# WinApi. Get file attributes for a mounted disk with administrator rights

Tags: winapi, mounted-volumes

There is a mounted network drive for example Y:\

If I just execute the code `GetFileAttributesW("Y:\")`, then everything will be fine and the answer will be "Operation completed successfully"

But if I execute the same code but with administrator rights, there will be an error "The system cannot find the specified path"

What the error may be related to, and how it can be fixed (if possible) ?

I tried to elevate privileges, as in `BOOL EnablePrivilege()`
[WindowsProcess.c](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/ManagementInfrastructure/cpp/Process/Provider/WindowsProcess.c)
But it didn't work out

Comment: I'm guessing that `Y:` is a user-specific mount point. If you're asking for it from a program that runs under a different user account, that volume isn't there.

Comment: Yes, drive letter mappings are user-specific. So, when running as an admin, you will have to impersonate the target user in order to access that user's drive letters. Otherwise, query the network drive using its UNC path instead

Comment: FYI, *enabling* privileges is not the same thing as gaining *elevated* privileges. You can't simply add privileges to gain admin rights, you can only enable/disable privileges you already have. Non-admin users don't have admin privileges which they can enable/disable. So you have to run as an admin user to begin with, or at least impersonate an admin user, in order to gain access to admin privileges.

Comment: error "The system cannot find the specified path" - I tried to elevate privileges - and where here logic ?

Answer (score 0):

[WNetAddConnection3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection3w#remarks) gives an adequate explanation:

> On Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP, the WNet functions create and
> delete network drive letters in the MS-DOS device namespace associated
> with a logon session because MS-DOS devices are identified by
> AuthenticationID (a locally unique identifier, or LUID, associated
> with a logon session.) This can affect applications that call one of
> the WNet functions to create a network drive letter under one user
> logon, but query for existing network drive letters under a different
> user logon. An example of this situation could be when a user's second
> logon is created within a logon session, for example, by calling the
> CreateProcessAsUser function, and the second logon runs an application
> that calls the **GetLogicalDrives** function. The call to the
> GetLogicalDrives function does not return network drive letters
> created by WNet function calls under the first logon. Note that in the
> preceding example the first logon session still exists, and the
> example could apply to any logon session, including a Terminal
> Services session. For more information, see Defining an MS-DOS Device
> Name.
>
> On Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP, if a service that runs as
> LocalSystem calls the **WNetAddConnection3** function, then the mapped
> drive is visible to all user logon sessions.